# How do I pull holidays events with Google Calendar API, more than 1 year ago?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I've been using the google calendar API in order to build a data set that contains:

1. Name of a holiday
2. Start Date
3. End Date
4. Region
   For example, I've used the following endpoint for holidays in the UK:

`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.uk%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key= + token`

Unfortunately it only worked for events since 2021 and until the end of 2023.
Is there a way to pull older information? using the timeMin argument for the request did not help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one imports that calendar using the user-interface, they'll notice there's no event older than 1 January 2021. The same behavior can be noticed in other holiday calendars.

Most likely this kind of calendar updates its events each year, so that events corresponding to holidays from previous years are removed.

Therefore, this is not related to Calendar API. The events you are looking for do not exist.